# perl - Data::UUID module

Tags: perl, uuid

I'm trying to run a perl script and I get this error:

```
Can't locate loadable object for module Data::UUID in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /var/www/cgi-bin/tmp.pl line 19
Compilation failed in require at /var/www/cgi-bin/tmp.pl line 19.
```

I installed "Data::UUID" manually (without Makefile.pl) and I'm not sure about what I'm doing wrong.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe explain *how* you "installed" the module.

Answer (score 2):

```
Can't locate loadable object for module Data::UUID
```

This means it's missing an object file. You should use the `Makefile.PL` to install this module, it's not "pure" perl, it has a native code part.

Comment: this is the message i get when i do MakeFile.PL

"Configured options (run perl Makefile.PL --help for how to change this):
        UUID state storage: /tmp
        default umask: 0007
Writing Makefile for Data::UUID
"

Comment: If you're having trouble with the `Makefile.PL` part, post a question about that with the **complete** output and more details about what platform you're running (windows? linux? (if Linux, what distribution?))

Comment: just did .. thanks Mat

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719686/perl-makefile-pl-help