# How do I deal with a missing CORE/config.h when building a Perl module?

Tags: perl, makefile

Every time I try to use Makefile.PL to install Data::UUID, I get this:

```
perl Makefile.PL
Configured options (run perl Makefile.PL --help for how to change this):
        UUID state storage: /tmp
        default umask: 0007
Writing Makefile for Data::UUID
```

Then when I run `make`, I get this:

```
make: *** No rule to make target /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/i386-linux-thread-multi/CORE/config.h', needed by Makefile'. Stop.
```

How can I deal with this?

I'm using Fedora, by the way.

Comment: please edit your post to specify what OS you are running.

Comment: And accept an answer if one was correct...

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for way late reply jack, but this might be useful for others who are new to managing linux packages.

As Grrrr pointed out you should install a perl-devel package.  If managing packages and perl modules are new to you perhaps you will appreciate a step by step answer...

To view installed packages execute:

```
  rpm -qa | grep perl-devel
```

if perl-devel is installed it will be listed like this:

```
  [root@gonzo ~]# rpm -qa |grep perl-devel
  perl-devel-5.10.1-115.el6.x86_64
  [root@gonzo ~]#
```

if it is not installed, execute:

```
  yum install perl-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your distribution's package manager to make sure the package that provides the missing file has been installed.

Comment: how can i go about doing that?

Comment: @jack, it's probably called `perl-dev` or something like that.

Comment: im sorry about this .. but this is totally new to me

this is what i get

"perl -dev

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.3 Editor support available.

Enter h or h h' for help, orman perldebug' for more help.

Comment: "Install the `perl-dev` package" does not mean "Run `perl -dev`", it means "install the `perl-dev` package".

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Fedora, this would be

`yum install perl-devel`